# How do I regex match a pattern with optional surrounding parentheses?

Tags: .net, regex, parentheses, option-type

I'm looking for a single line regular expression which matches a pattern with optional parentheses. When the parentheses are present they should not be included in the matched pattern.

The following bold text demonstrates what should / shouldn't match:

**Should Match:**

> "Title Description (**AAA123**)"
>
> "(**ABC000**) Title Description"
>
> "Title Description **DEF999**"
>
> "Title - **RST321** - Description"

**Shouldn't Match:**

> "Title Description AB123"
>
> "Title Description CCC456a"
>
> "Title Description (ABE999c)"

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: @Rohit Jain Instead of making it a good edit. You messed it.

Comment: @RohitJain: Tried this "()?([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3})()?" but it matches the end character regardless of whether its a parenthesis or not

Comment: @BrianScott: What language are you using?

Comment: @nhahtdh: Using .Net but can translate any regex statement as required.

Comment: Do you want `DFG456` in `Title_Description_DFG456` to be matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{3}\b
```

This matches:

```
# \b          - A word boundary,
# [a-zA-Z]{3} - followed by 3 letters,
# \d{3}       - followed by 3 digits,
# \b          - followed by a word boundary.
```

The regex doesn't care about parentheses, like requested, but doesn't match strings that are too long.

Comment: You will also match `___345` and `234456`

Comment: @nhahtdh: Whoops, I didn't think of `\w` also matching those. Edited, thanks!

Comment: @Cerbrus: Excellent, the \b was the missing key for me. I didn't know how to match either empty space or a parenthesis at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, @Brian! I'd suggest having a look at [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info), it has a lot of useful info on regexes. Thanks for accepting my answer ^_^